# Angular 2+ and subjects

Tags: angular, rxjs

I found angular subject simple example in the internet. I try to use code from example, using subject but i don't getting any result for workTime variable. Where's the problem?

Work.service.ts

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class WorkService {

  public $workTimeSubject: Subject<number> = new Subject();

  constructor() { }
}
```

app.component.ts:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private _workService: WorkService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._workService.$workTimeSubject.next(40);
    console.log('app init');

    this._workService.setWorkTime(40);
  }
}
```

Boss.component.ts:

```
export class BossComponent implements OnInit {

  workTime: number;

  constructor(private _workService: WorkService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._workService.$workTimeSubject.subscribe((value) => {
      this.workTime = value;
      console.log('value', value);
    });
  }
}
```

boss.component.ts

```
{{ workTime }}
```

Comment: bossComponent is child of appComponent

Comment: What does `console.log('value', value);` print?

Comment: it prints nothing, I mean, even 'value' is not printed

Comment: i think you should use behavior Subject as it will always store previous value so even if you subscribe after the value has been set , you'll get the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few modifications in your code, please check

**Work.service.ts:**

```
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import "rxjs/Rx";

@Injectable()
export class WorkService {

  private $workTimeSubject: Subject<number> = new Subject();

  updateWorkTime(time: number) {
    this.$workTimeSubject.next(time);
  }

  getWorkTime(): Observable<any> {
    return this.$workTimeSubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts:**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

  constructor(private _workService: WorkService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._workService.updateWorkTime(40);
    console.log('app init');
  }
}
```

**Boss.component.ts:**

```
export class BossComponent implements OnInit {

  workTime: number;
  subscription: Subscription;

  constructor(private _workService: WorkService) {
    this.subscription = this._workService.getWorkTime().subscribe(time => { this.workTime = time; });
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem was, I set function with subscribtion in ngOnInit, not constructor.

Comment: You should set it in ngOnInit. The constuctor should be used for dependency injection. Please check out my answer.

Comment: But what with that subscription in constructor of boss.component?

Answer (score 0):

The `AppComponent` emits the value before `BossComponent` has the chance to subscribe. If you want the Subject to replay the last emited value to new subscribers use `ReplaySubject`.

Replace:
`public $workTimeSubject: Subject<number> = new Subject();`

With:
`public $workTimeSubject: ReplaySubject<number> = new ReplaySubject(1);`